# Why "loading" is considered as a keyword while audited for SEO?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, seo, keyword

Following is the extract taken from the HTML source of the home page of my site hosted on internet. The site is built using ASP.NET MVC 4 and JQuery

```
<span class="scopesmalltitle  wordwrap">
<span class="scopeNameText wordwrap " scopeNameContainer="true" scopetypeid=073c2278-23e9-4831-94b3-e528d846ba68>
Loading...
</span>
</span>
```

The above HTML exists in the HTML source for newly 10 or more places (depending upon differnt scopetypeid in database). I have written a JQuery code to replace that "loading..." text by the actual text in database after the page is loaded.

The problem is that, when I do audit of my website from any SEO checking site such as "rankingtoday.com", etc. I get to see "loading..." is considered as the keyword, and it is giving a warning of overuse.

Why does "loading.." counted in keywords? and how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It appears in the content of your site when it gets crawled.

Comment: It's counted because the search engine spider is only counting content available on the page on load, ie. before any AJAX requests have completed. There is nothing you can do about this as it is entirely down to how the spider is coded to behave.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about programming; it may belong on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @T.J. Crowser - that's true, but there are many other contents as well in the same site, and so why most of them are not counted as Keywords?

Comment: @Rory - you mean to say, such warnings do not affect how the website  will be treated by search engines?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, is HTML and JQuery not about programming? May be the question is for 20% programming and 80% SEO... that doesn't mean, it should be rejected straight-away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because before any javascript is executed, the word "Loading" is overused in the processed html file.

To overcome this, you could remove "loading" use a jquery selector to get the spans and set the values like this:

```
$( "span[scopetypeid='whatever']" ).html('whatever text');
```